Stalks of nonarchimedean spaces as analytic rings
Let $(A,A^+)$ be an affinoid Tate ring, and let $x \in X=\operatorname{Spa}(A,A^+)$. When defining the stalks of the structure sheafs ${\mathcal O}_{X,x} = \varinjlim_{x \in U} {\mathcal O}_{X}(U) $ and ${\mathcal O}_{X,x}^+ = \varinjlim_{x \in U} {\mathcal O}_{X}^+(U)$, colimits over all rational opens $U$ containing $x$, most authors tend to ignore the analytic structure (and even the topology) of the rings ${\mathcal O}_{X}(U)$, the reason being that the direct limit topology is not $f$-adic and there is no canonical choice for the topology. There are various ways to work around this issue. However, in Clausen and Scholze's theory of analytic rings, the colimit $A_x=\varinjlim_{x \in U} ({\mathcal O}_{X}(U), {\mathcal O}_{X}^+(U))_{\square} $ exists as an analytic ring!
I would like to compute the underlying ring $A_x^{\triangleright}(\ast)$ in the simplest concrete example, say we take $X$ to be the closed unit disk over $\operatorname{Spa}(\mathbb{Q}_p,\mathbb{Z}_p)$. My guess is that  $A_x^{\triangleright}(\ast)$ should be something like the completed residue field $\widehat{k(x)}$ if $x$ has generic support, but I'm very curious to know: What  is $A_x^{\triangleright}(\ast)$ if $x$ is a rigid point? I don't think it should be $\widehat{k(x)}$ because each of the rings in the colimit contains a copy of $\mathbb{Q}_p\langle t \rangle$, so it seems their colimit should as well.
One thing that I am having trouble with is that, since the colimits are filtered, from Dustin Clausen's lecture on analytic stacks it seems that already the colimit $A_x^\text{pre}$ in preanalytic rings is complete, but even when $x$ is not rigid $(A_x^\text{pre})^{\triangleright}(\ast)$ seem to be just $k(x)$, instead of $\widehat{k(x)}$, I seem to be doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what it is.

Sorry for ignorance. What are rigid points? As far as I know, there are five classes of points in the rigid closed unit disk.

By that I mean a point $x$ such that $[\widehat{k(x)}:\mathbb{Q}_p]$ is finite. All of them are type I, but not every point of type I is rigid. I guess I was thinking about that case first, but I would be happy to know the answer over $\mathbb{C}_p$, where all type I points are rigid.

In the special case of $x$ being the origin of the closed unit disk, it is the ring of overconvergent functions at the origin, with induced analytic structure from $\mathbb Q_{p,\square}$.

I see, thank you! So is just $\varinjlim_n \mathbb{Q}_p\langle T/p^n \rangle$, no completion needed. Does that mean at the Gauss point $x$ you also get the uncompleted $k(x)$? I would have thought the analytic spectrum of $A_x$ would correspond to ${\rm Spa}(\widehat{k(x)})$.

Would it be fair to say that ${\rm AnSpec}(A_x)$ is the fiber product of ${\rm Spa}(k(x)){dR} \rightarrow X{dR}$ along the map $X \rightarrow X_{dR}$. That is,  the thickening of ${\rm Spa}(k(x))={\rm Spa}(\widehat{k(x)})$ were you adjoint all points infinitesimally (overconvergently) close to x? I think that works out in the case you mentioned.
